# Order of execution of join and correlated subquery works in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, Table_A, Table_B, Table_C

Table_A has around 1000 rows,
Table_B has around 10 million rows,
Table_C has around 10 million rows,

Table_B and Table_C has around 7 million common rows

I joined all these three tables as per my requirement as below:

```
select *from Table_A A Left join Table_B B
on A.id=B.id
where
Not Exists
(select 1 from Table_C C where C.id=B.id )
```

So my Question is what will be the order of execution,i.e will the **Table_B** and **Table_C** be compared first on id  and filter out common 7 million rows and then join will be executed with **Table_A** to filter 1000 rows which not exists in 7 million rows

or

**Table_A** will join with **Table_B** and fetch 1000 rows ,and then these 1000 rows of **Table_B** will be compared with **Table_C**

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Only tag the RDBMS you are "really* using.

Comment: Also, I actually suggest a little less white space. Too little isn't good, but neither is too much.

Comment: have you tried to use `explain` against the query? also, kinda weird you changed the query.

Comment: The idea behind a modern RDBMS is that you should not have to worry about that. The optimizer will - most of the time - pick a decent way of evaluating your query. Some DBMS are better at this than others. I suggest that you study the access plan for your DBMS to see how it will evaluate the query.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is entirely dependant on how your DBMS’s query optimiser decides to execute the query

Answer (score 0):

It depends by the DBMS or you could influencing the optimizer by using the optimizer hints.